# Robert Rankin book where a character is described as wearing a seven-piece suit

Tags: story-identification, books

A typical three-piece suit is a matching jacket, trousers and waistcoat.

However I know that somewhere in a Robert Rankin book he describes a character (maybe Hugo Rune) dressed in a seven-piece suit; I think it included a top hat and an overcoat but that only makes it five items.

Can anyone please identify the book I can't remember, and detail what a seven-piece suit is made up of?

Edit/update
It's been identified as a 6 piece suit, not a 7 piece In the Witches of Chiswick.

I'll accept that answer provisionally

But now I've a memory of a cloak being part of the ensemble!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are you certain it was a seven-piece suit, rather than six-piece? A man is described as wearing a six-piece suit (including a topcoat and top hat) in Robert Rankin's *[The Witches of Chiswick](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2044733.The_Witches_of_Chiswick)* (2003):

> The mighty figure's apparel was of the most striking and elaborate confection. **A six-piece suit of lime green Boleskine tweed, with matching shirt and trousers, jacket and waistcoat and topcoat and top hat too.** Affixed to the band of the tweedy topper was a large golden brooch in the shape of a five-pointed star and inlaid with many precious stones. Upon the waistcoat hung numerous watch-chains, similarly of gold, from which depended fobs of the Masonic persuasion. Upon the third finger of the great right hand, which presently held young Winston aloft, was a ring of power, set with a star sapphire and engraved all about with enigmatic symbols. In the left hand was a swordstick topped by a silver skull.

Comment: I am having difficulty imagining a shirt of lime green Boleskine tweed.  A top hat *maybe*, but a tweed shirt would just be an instrument of torture.

Comment: What exactly is Boleskine tweed? And how is it different from normal tweed?

Comment: Boleskine tweed only exists in-universe. It references Boleskine House near Dores on Loch Ness which was once the home of Aleister Crowley.